# How to change some range values in entire list with Linq

Tags: c#, linq, range

I've a list like this:

```
property = Enumerable.Range(0, 999).Select(i => 0).ToList();
```

All of values are 0. I want to change some values in some ranges. For example;

(0, 333) = must be 0

(334, 666) = must be 1

(667,999) = must be 2

Is there a way to do this in Linq?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var query = Enumerable.Range(0, 999).Select((n, index) =>
            {
                if (index <= 333)
                    return 0;
                else if (index <= 666)
                    return 1;
                else
                    return 2;
            });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, Can I find how much indexes have same value continuously? For example query[0]=query[1]=query[2]=query[3] = 0, query[4] = 1, query[5]=query[6] = 0. First three indexes have 0, so first answer is 3. Also Last two indexes have 0, so second answer is 2.. How can I find these?

Comment: @team16sah that sounds like a nice question to me. Note, stackoverflow.com is not really keen on users 'asking for a piece of code'. Before you ask your question, try it out yourself and show that in said question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this extension method:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static void SetRangeValues<T>(this IList<T> source, int start, int end, T value)
    {
        if (start > 0 && end < source.Count)
        {
            for (int i = start; i <= end; i++)
            {
                source[i] = value;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Usage:

```
list.SetRangeValues(0,333,0);
list.SetRangeValues(334,666,1);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the integer division trick.

```
var property = Enumerable.Range(0, 999).Select(i => i/333).ToList();
```

a simple test case:

```
Enumerable.Range(0, 9).Select(x => x / 3).ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

Comment: `666/333 = 2`, where in his example `666 == 1` and `667 == 2`